# Viewstate Error in webpage

Tags: asp.net, web

The following error occurs when my webpage is idle for more than 5 min.

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
Source File: http://www.dial4jobz.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=Xl5p0QQ_qaR3K9bIVhwC3LyqjOX_oAKyeLj_-uS5j1VoFExVtm3XAHiq64EGJt04xntLJvh-9y3pvN3dvKgg5b6sQwkFvX7GT4f0aKn7iyc1&t=73e6f815

Dono, wat is the cause of this error.. I'll open a web page and after 5 min when I'm accessing it, it is showing this sort of error.. I don't hav any clue that why this error occurs.. Plz, give me any idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code and try

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" />
```

if u need more info kindly refer the link below,

http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/p/955145/1173230.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this is the two solutions I found and that might help if you are not  using a WebFarm:

**1. Disable ViewState MAC**

On your page (.aspx) @Page directive you can add the attribute `EnableViewStateMac="false"`. By doing this that will disable the check and then the issue will goes away.

Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't recommend to do this for security reasons:

> This attribute should never be set to **false** in a production Web site,
>   even if the application or page does not use view state. The view
>   state MAC helps ensure the security of other ASP.NET functions in
>   addition to view state.

Source: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac.aspx)

**2. Check HTML**

There is a bug in ASP.Net causing this issue when the "`action`" attribute is set in your `<form>` tag. For example:

```
<form runat="server" action="page.aspx">
```

By removing this attribute that will remove the issue, so you should now have something like:

```
<form runat="server">
```

Obviously this solution may raise other issues, it depends on your application. One big problem is when using Ajax to load pages.

**3. Avoid ViewStates**

In some cases when using Ajax it could be very easy to get rid of ViewStates. You can send Ajax requests to your server for performing operations and then display the result, no need to use a ViewState. By doing this you won't have an issue about the ViewState validation.

I also found other suggestions on [those pages](http://forums.asp.net/t/955145.aspx/33/10?PageIndex=20) that might help you if what said above doesn't fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hai vaishu,
  Have a look at this [validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error](http://alpascual.com/blog/how-to-fix-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-in-ajax/)